# Consuming web services with reporting tools

Tags: web-services, reporting-services, reporting

A customer of mine happend to ask me to come up with a technical solution 
for the following scenario:

- basis is a crm tool where the customers (i.e. the ones who bought the system)
  are not wanted to access the database for queries directly (in terms of table level access)
- there's plenty of reporting in the software, but sometimes it's just not
  exactky what's needed, so some sort of interface for external reporting tools is
  required.

--> beeing 'state of the art' my customer want's to use web services for this;
which IMHO is definitly not the way to do this; I'd favorize the creation
of VIEWS which the crm customers can use to feed their reporting tools via ODBC
for example.

So, what's you guys opinion on this, how would you approach this scenario? Any best practices?

Comment: allright, you guys 'conviced' me. i'll do some more research on how to come up with a WS based solution. thx for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about empowering the customer to be able to write custom modules or plugins to the CRM software? If the built in reports don't suffice, they can quickly roll out their plugin to accomplish their objectives. IMO, exposing APIs is a much better approach. Also. there's nothing wrong with customers accessing the database tables directly. But the latter approach may be more cumbersome to some customers.

Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

I thing that web-services is a nice solution. Using VIEWS - is using db authorization. While using WS you can be more secure  :-)

Comment: that's right so far, but I think transfering big amounts of data via soap is not an (optimal) option at all.

Comment: you can zip stream between ws and client.

Comment: Here you have to ask yourself the question "Do I want to reimplement Crystal Reports?"  Because that's almost what you're doing.  On the flip-side, I find most people don't use Crystal anymore unless they're only job is data analysis.  Most are using excel or one off tools.  I'm not sure if excel supports WS data sources yet, but this is clearly where the industry is going.  Clearly delineated XML data being queried (and paginated server side) for consumption by end-users.  The biggest hit is in the XML parsing, unfortunately.  So create a rich search API.

Comment: Excel 2007 support web services. If like Excel you can use it. I used Excel 2007 with Team Foundation Server to build some reports.